# How memory intensive is a list of SPItems?

Tags: object-model

I want to create a list which can store SPItems for "offline" reference.

I would hope no more than 3000-6000 items.

Do you think this is pushing it memory wise?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many columns and what type of columns?

Comment: What do you mean with "offline" reference - just store the list as a file or something on the disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just saved a list as a dataset and converted to an xml recordset into a text file.   This list contains 15 custom columns with several of them being lookup columns.  It has 2345 items in list.  The file ended up being almost 7 MB.  This might give you some hint into the size.

Answer (score 1):

3000-6000 items in a list is not much for SharePoint which can scale to very very large amounts of items.

Of course working with a large items takes its special toll. For instance SharePoint has built-in throttling that (by default) stops you from retreiving more that 5.000 items at once. You need to make sure that you query the list smart to retrieve all items. Displaying views with a "lot of items" can degrade performance severly, etc etc